# How to interpraet skyscanner flight api polling output data?

Tags: php, api, skyscanner

I want to use skyscanner flight api in my application in order to fetch and display flight scheduled between two airports. I've got the data from api but not able to interpret it.

below is the link where you can see the api output

https://github.com/Skyscanner/api-documentation/blob/master/live_flights_pricing/sample_live_flights_pricing_response.json

I want to show data like this
[image]

What is inbound and outbound IDs? What is a leg and segment?
Where to use leg and segment?
What is PricingOptions ?

Comment: Read the API manual.

Comment: I have read the manual. I am getting same data as I provided link but I am confused about how to use and put this data in UI.